# Why does Maxima give me an error on plot2d when trying to draw a parametric graph?

Tags: plot, graph, drawing, draw, maxima

I am trying to draw a parametric graph in Maxima. The code I enter is this:

```
wxplot2d([parametric, t^2/(t-1), t/(t^2-1), [t, 0, 2*%pi], [nticks, 300]]);
```

But I get the following error:

```
plot2d: parametric plots must include two expressions and an interval
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong, since it does include two expressions and an interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small error. It should be

```
wxplot2d([parametric, t^2/(t-1), t/(t^2-1), [t, 0, 2*%pi]], [nticks, 300]);
```